ActionServlet.process() equivalent in Spring
Working to upgrade my application from Struts 1.2.9 to Spring MVC. The application currently has a class extending ActionServlet.java and overrides its process() method to capture and log the time taken to process each request/action for performance monitoring purposes.
I am looking for something similar in Spring MVC. I've gone through the DispatcherServlet javadoc but didn't find anything useful there.
Basically, I am looking for a way to implement centralized performance logging for all requests in Spring MVC.

You're probably looking for a HandlerInterceptor.
